# A new thread object that has not been started will be garbage collected?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

---

I have the source code from a Java Virtual Machine. This VM only garbage collect threads which fullfill these conditions (both conditions):

- Thread is finished (**started** and **finished**)
- Thread object does not have any reference

I think it was supposed to garbage collect a **not started thread** with **no refence**. But these threads are being held in the VM memory. Is that correct ?

---

**Sample Code:**

```
public class Test implements Runnable{

    private Thread thread;
    public Test() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }    

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //This thread never runs...
        //My question is about garbage collector in a situation like this...
    }    
}
```

**Considering:**

- Test object does not have reference anymore
- The Test object thread never started

---

The **Test thread** will be garbage collected ?

Comment: I'm creating a Virtual Machine, so i need to know the concept. For this reason i'm asking for help here :)

Comment: The `Thread` instance is not the actual thread, it is the api to control the thread. Once there is a running thread your `Thread` object will be referenced "from the thread" and can't be GC'd while that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of `Thread` or `Runnable` class is like an instance of any other class. So, yes it will be GCed if the reference goes out of scope.

Note : You will first have to create an instance of `Test`.

A *running* thread acts as root for GC and will not be GCed. Its *starting* the thread (by calling `start()` that actually creates a *executing thread* and makes it special.

Comment: @GabrielDias - A thread that is not started is like any other object and will be GCed that way. A thread that is *executing* will not be GCed because running threads will serve as GC roots